# ¿Cómo hacer una app desktop de pre-pago en Java con la IDE Netbeans y MySQL como SGBD?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, aplicación-escritorio

Actualmente tengo un proyecto `Java` en IDE Netbeans y una Base de Datos en MySQL.

Lo que deseo hacer es que a determinada fecha la aplicación no permita ingresar (Expire la fecha de uso) hasta que e administrador mediante algún especie de token permita el ingreso a la aplicación.

Actualmente esa es la idea, pero desconozco que linea seguir para llegar a lograr el propósito de la aplicación.

**Avance e investigación al respecto**

Básicamente cuento con el proyecto funcionando, el cual tiene un Login para validar el ingreso al sistema, he investigado y no he encontrado nada al respecto a lo que deseo hacer. Diseñando un poco la idea, encontré la siguiente alternativa, pero tiene problemas que no logro solucionar:

**Alternativa:**

- En la base de Datos establezco una fecha la cual el sistema compararía con la fecha del ordenador, en la cual veo el problema de alterar la fecha de la pc y poder ingresar. Por lo que pienso que el obtenerla mediante conexión a internet pudiera ser la solución. (Esto es de una manera muy burda)
- El siguiente problema es la modificación del token, como establecer la comparación de la base de datos (en la que seria agregado) con el sistema para que permita el ingreso sin ningún problema.

Comment: La pregunta es un tanto amplia y pudiera terminar cerrada, checa [ask]

Comment: @Aprendiz de que forma pudiera formularla para que no se cierre?

Comment: Agregando lo que lleves hecho o investigado al momento